# Refugee status for a South African citizen

Tags: immigration, asylum, refugees

I have a friend desperate to leave South Africa due to the ongoing looting and violence happening there in the last few days. Life is going to be very difficult with food shortages and all kind of issues due to the unrest. She is a 24 year old Afrikaner girl. What chances does she have to get refugee status and to which country could she apply?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suspect that her chance of being accepted as a refugee is low.  To qualify as a refugee, she would have to demonstrate "a well-founded fear of being persecuted for reasons of race, religion, nationality, membership of a particular social group or political opinion" and that she cannot, because of that fear or for other reasons, be protected from that persecution by South Africa.  Having a hard time of it because of social unrest is not sufficient; she has to have a reason to fear that she herself is or might become a target of persecution.

If she can demonstrate that fear, then she can apply at least to any country that has ratified the [1967 protocol to the Convention on the Status of Refugees](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Protocol_Relating_to_the_Status_of_Refugees), which are shown in yellow and dark green on this map (other countries might have similar provisions in their national law without having ratified the protocol):

[image: map]